# Mysql query with counts or parental records

Tags: mysql, join

I having following two tables:

```
reviews table:
id

visits table:
id
review_id
```

I am trying to display reviews list for those reviews with least one visit record.
tried to LEFT OUTER JOIN with HAVING (and GROUP) but that gives me reviews with count of all its visits.
Planning to produce table like this:
Review #1 - 2 visits
Review #2 - 10 visits
.. etc., reviews with 0 visits ignored

Comment: You don't show where the number of visits is stored. The "visits" table just has an 'id' (presumably a unique record ID) and a 'review_id' (presumably a FK into the "reviews" table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select r.id,count(v.id) from reviews r inner join visits v on r.id=v.review_id 
GROUP BY v.review_id
```

Won't need to use LEFT JOIN as INNER JOIN will only return matching records which in this case meaning will return those with visits.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    r.id,
    count(v.id) as Reviews
from reviews r 
left join visits v on r.id=v.review_id 
GROUP BY v.review_id
having Reviews > =1
```